# OAuth2::Error , Sign in issue with Oauth-facebook

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

**This is the error I am getting once I click on sign up and authorize the app with Facebook.**

```
: {"error":{"message":"Error validating application. Invalid application     ID.","type":"OAuthException","code":101}}
```

I don't know how to fix this and where the error is coming from. Here is my omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :developer unless Rails.env.production?
  provider :facebook, ['I_PUT_MY_API_ID_KEY'], ['I_PUT_MY_API_SECRET_KEY'],
  :scope => 'email, user_relationships, user_status,user_about_me publish_actions',    :display => 'popup'
end
```

Comment: Just to verify, you do have your real api key/secret, not I_PUT_MY_API_ID_KEY and I_PUT_MY_API_SECRET_KEY  in the file, right?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. It seems sporadic. I can't reproduce it, and users who have filed bug reports report that it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked without the brackets when I took off "[" and "]"

Answer (score 2):

mybe use
`provider :facebook, ['I_PUT_MY_API_ID_KEY'], ['I_PUT_MY_API_SECRET_KEY']` 
to
`provider :facebook, "I_PUT_MY_API_ID_KEY", "I_PUT_MY_API_SECRET_KEY"`